# How do you flip the inverted pyramid?

Tags: loops

So I need to create an hourglass using two asterisks triangle in a function with one parameter. My problem is I am not sure how to flip it. I got the regular triangle down but it is still not fully correct:

I would like to put my code here to show what I did. But I’m not sure how u do that here?

However the print part is supposed to look like this.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJrzV.jpg
And the output should look like this: 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q5Ez.jpg)

Comment: Please read about asking [Minimal Complete and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What have you tried so far? For that matter, what language are you using?

Comment: [How to insert piece of code to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) Try to add code, I'm sure someone would help you